# How to create Expandable Cell with Dynamic height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, customization

I have two fields in my project one for question and another for answer. How can i display answers by clicking on question on table view.

Comment: You can keep cell status is open or close in one array.If cell status change you can reload tableView and   change height in  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
}

Answer (score 0):

You could treat each expandable cell as a section. For each section you just feed  it with different number of data models and reload the tableview, you could see tableview adjust number of rows in that section.For example you implement tableview datasource like this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.feedEntitySections.count;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.feedEntitySections[section] numberOfRows];
}
```

Take section 0 for example, it has 3 rows when expanded and only 1 row when folded. You could implement you expand action like this.

```
    //Expand section 0.
    [self expandSectionAtIndex:0];

    //Fold section 0.
    [self foldSectionAtIndex:0];

- (void)expandSectionAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    self.feedEntitySections[idx].numberOfRows = 3;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)foldSectionAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    self.feedEntitySections[idx].numberOfRows = 1;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this answers the question.